# Extracting folder

Tags: python

I am using the code below to extract a file from a folder

```
path = Clinical_data.get_path()

with paths.get_download_stream("paths") as f:
        data = f.read()
```

But I get this error:
<class 'AttributeError'>: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_download_stream'

How do i pass the content of paths into f using  'get_download_stream'

I will like to use f in the line of code below

adrs_files= glob.glob(os.path.join(Clinical_data.get_path(), 'adrs_*.sas7bdat'))

Comment: looks like `get_path()` returns a list

Comment: yes it does, what can i replace it with ?